# Node.js asynchronous control flow with 3 processes working on shared data

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async.js

I have node.js app with 3 functions, each one has own interval (or can by fired by another event):

- processOrders
- clearExpiredOrders
- clearCancelledOrders

Functions are working on shared data, so only one of them can access this data at the time.

When there is a collision, it should wait until the actual function ends and then run second function immediately, but only once.

For example, if there is **processOrders** running and **clearCancelledOrders** is triggered 100 times, it will run **clearCancelledOrders** only once after **processOrders** finishes its work.

How would you solve this in node.js? Or do you have another idea how to solve this task?

Comment: You need a message queue and your requirements are still ill-defined. Please research more before posting here. Try Kue. Also look at the design of RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ.

Comment: Specifically it's incomplete because you don't define when clearCancelledOrders becomes reenabled. Proper concurrency control here makes this a huge question. For "getting started," message queueing should give you something to google, and if you have a start may be okay to post a question here.

Comment: I will look at it, originally I expected something like promises or event based solution where I can't exactly imagine how it should work for my task.. but I will do research about message queues

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do this very simply with promises:

```
var p  = Promise.resolve(); // assuming Bluebird promises or Node 0.11.13+ with Promises.
                            // create a new empty resolved promise.

function doFirst(act){
   return p = p.then(function(){
      return someFirstAction(act); // assumes someFirstAction returns a promise
   })
}
function doSecond(act){
   return p p.then(function(){
      return someSecondAction(act); // assumes someFirstAction returns a promise
   })
}
```

What this does is *queue* the operations on the single chain. When it resolves the chain resolves. It also returns the returned promise, so you can unwrap it and get the value.

For example:

```
doFirst(1);
doSecond(2);

// some point in the future
doFirst(3).then(function(value){
   // both doFirst(1) and doSecond(2) are done here
   // the value argument is the resolution value of doFirst(3)
});
```

If you're unsure on how to convert your API to promises - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises).

Since, you also want to limit the number of times a particular action is run, you can create special methods for it:

```
doFirst.queued = false;
function doFirst(act){
   if(doFirst.queued) return; // already queued
   doFirst.queued = true;
   return p = p.then(function(){
      return someFirstAction(act).finally(function(){ 
          doFirst.queued = false;
      }); 
   })
}
doSecond.queued = false;
function doSecond(act){
   if(doSecond.queued) return; // already queued
   doSecond.queued = true; 
   return p = p.then(function(){
        return someSecondAction(act); // assumes someFirstAction returns a promise
   }).finally(function(){
        doSecond.queued = false;
   });
}
```

Comment: Queuing by `.then()` is not enough here. OP wants that "*if clearCancelledOrders is triggered 100 times [during some other processing], it will run clearCancelledOrders only once [after the other task]*"

Comment: Oh, I totally missed that although it's huge and bold, my bad. Lemme fix that.